# Getting HashMap associated with particular item in ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, arraylist

I have a `ListView` where I am showing items in an `ArrayList` fetched from a URL in JSON format. Each item consists of 5 elements. I want to pass the elements associated with that particular list item when it is clicked to another activity. But when I pass the `ArrayList` to the other activity and iterate the `ArrayList` only the last item in the list opens up no matter which list item I click on.

Here is my code:

MainActivity.java

```
JSONArray jObject = new JSONArray(responseBody);
for (int i = 0; i < jObject.length(); i++) {
  JSONObject menuObject = jObject.getJSONObject(i);
  String title= menuObject.getString("Title");
  String description= menuObject.getString("BodyText");
  String thumbnail= menuObject.getString("ThumbnailPath");
  String nUrl = menuObject.getString("Url");
  String body = menuObject.getString("Body");
  String nBigImage = menuObject.getString("ImageBlobUrls");

  map = new HashMap<String,String>();
  map.put(SOURCETITLE, title);
  map.put(TITLE, description);
  map.put(THUMBNAILPATH, thumbnail);
  map.put(BODY, body);
  map.put(URL, nUrl);
  map.put(IMAGEBLOBURLS,nBigImage);

  myList.add(map);
}

myListView.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);
myListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent nIntent = new Intent(Home.this,NDetails.class);
        nIntent.putExtra("myItems", myList);
        startActivity(nIntent);
    }
});
```

NDetails.java

```
Intent in = getIntent();

    data =  (ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>) in.getSerializableExtra("myItems");

    for(Map<String, String> newItem:data)
    {
         newUrl = newItem.get(Home.URL);
         newTitle =newItem.get(Home.SOURCETITLE);
         newBody= newItem.get(Home.BODY);
         newImage = newItem.get(Home.THUMBNAILPATH);

    }


     txtNewsTitle.setText(newTitle);
     txtNewsBody.setText(newBody);
```

How do I resolve this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
myListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
                        {

                            @Override
                            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0,
                                    View arg1, int position, long arg3) 
                            {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                HashMap myMap = myList.get(position);
                                Intent nIntent = new Intent(Home.this,NDetails.class);
                                newsIntent.putExtra("myItems", myMap);
                                startActivity(nIntent);
                            }
                        });
```

and get map in another activity like this :

```
data =  (HashMap<String, String>>) in.getSerializableExtra("myItems");

newUrl = data.get(Home.URL);
     data =newItem.get(Home.SOURCETITLE);
     data= newItem.get(Home.BODY);
     data = newItem.get(Home.THUMBNAILPATH);
```

Comment: I tried your solution. But in the next activity I get an error `Can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable` when I try to iterate through the map

Comment: But in next activity don't make any iteration just get hashmap from intent and get get your data from that. no need of any arraylist and no need to iterate that list.

Answer (score 0):

```
myListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
    HashMap<String, String> item = ( HashMap<String, String>)arg0.getItemAtPosition(position);
    Intent nIntent = new Intent(Home.this,NDetails.class);
    newsIntent.putExtra("myItems", myList);
    startActivity(nIntent);
}
 });
```

you can use `AdapterView.getItemAtPosition(int)` to retrieve the element at position

Comment: how do I get elements at that particular position in the next activity?